# What water is kept in three brass kalanchi?

Tags: gods, rituals, identification-request, practice

I recently read an online article but now I cannot find the page. There are three brass kalanchi (kalanji) that are placed at the feet on deities. What is the purpose of these and what should be kept in them? I remember vaguely that it includes water for 3 distinct purposes but I cannot recall.

Comment: Is it related to Sri-Vaishanava Sampradaya?